# React Typescript: api data to array map

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

I have this array data from api and I want to make it in react tsx file using map function

```
{
   "data":{
      "cart":{
         "1":{
            "product_id":1,
            "name":"Product 1",
            "quantity":1,
            "price":"1.00"
         },
         "2":{
            "product_id":2,
            "name":"Product 2",
            "quantity":1,
            "price":"1.00"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

React Typescript Code (but not working):

```
(data.cart.map((item:any, key:any) => (
   <p>{item.product_id}</p>
   <p>{item.name}</p>
   <p>{item.quantity}</p>
   <p>{item.price}</p>
)))
```

I want to to fix the react tsx code

Comment: What's your error message?

Comment: console log:
TypeError: e.map is not a function

Answer (score 1):

The data is nested inside object within cart. You can use `Object.Keys` to access keys like 1, 2, 3 ...

```
Object.keys(data.cart[0]).map((key) => {
let item = data.cart[0][key];
return (
<React.Fragment key={key}>
   <p>{item.product_id}</p>
   <p>{item.name}</p>
   <p>{item.quantity}</p>
   <p>{item.price}</p>
</React.Fragment>
)
});
```

Based on revised question, since you removed array:

```
Object.keys(data.cart).map((key) => {
let item = data.cart[key];
return (
<React.Fragment key={key}>
   <p>{item.product_id}</p>
   <p>{item.name}</p>
   <p>{item.quantity}</p>
   <p>{item.price}</p>
</React.Fragment>
)
});
```

Comment: original api data: https://pastebin.com/LDYHF7BU

original react typescript code: https://pastebin.com/61yvU9Pb